# Custom template for view page

Tags: 7, views, theming

When i created custom template for view page using 'theme information' in views,it's not affecting the page.What is the proper way to create template for view pages?

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Comment: yes.i did.theme registry cache also cleared.nothing working out

Comment: If you go back to the view, and click on theme information. When the dialog opens, scroll down and click the rescan template files button. Does the new template file you created get highlighted?

Comment: yes.it's highlighted.

Comment: What did you call your file?

Comment: I usually put die(); in php file to crash-test if it is called or not.

Comment: file name is "views-view--compare-products.tpl.php".I have taken this file name from "Theme information" only.my view name is "compare_products".

Answer (score 1):

I think this pretty well covers it: [Views template files](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/group/views_templates/7)